# How to use Gson fromJson in this situation?

Tags: java, json, gson

I want to convert json to Java Obejct using Gson.

For example, Json structure is ...

```json
{
  "title": "title",
  "product" : [
    {
      "key": "product1",
      "value": [{
        "valueName": "productValue1"
      }]
      "date" : "2022-10-11"
    },
    {
      "key": "product2",
      "value": []
    },
    "date" : "2022-10-11"
  ]
}
```

I made DTOs like...

```java
public Class ProductDTO {
  String title;
  List<Product> product;
}

public Class Product {
  String key;
  List<Value> value;
}

public Class Value {
  String valueName;
}
```

And

```java
// payload: String
Gson gson = new Gson();
ProductDTO productDTO = gson.fromJson(payload, ProductDTO.class);
```

When executing fromJson, I had MalformedJsonException.
In json, value List size == 0 for "key": "product2"
But I have String valueName attribute in Value Class.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: The JSON data seems to be malformed, in front of the first `"date"` a `,` is missing, and the second `"date"` is in the JSON array instead of the object. Please use a tool such as https://jsonlint.com/ to verify the JSON is valid. Please also make sure the DTO code you provided here is correct, it currently uses `Class` instead of `class`. Please provide the full exception message of `MalformedJsonException` and also check it again yourself; it describes where exactly the issue is. Could you please also clarify what you mean by "In json, value List size == 0..."?

Answer (score 0):

I think your model classes will be like that

```
public class Product {

@SerializedName("key")
@Expose
private String key;
@SerializedName("value")
@Expose
private List<Value> value = null;

public String getKey() {
return key;
}

public void setKey(String key) {
this.key = key;
}

public List<Value> getValue() {
return value;
}

public void setValue(List<Value> value) {
this.value = value;
}

}
```

---

```
public class ProductDTO {

@SerializedName("title")
@Expose
private String title;
@SerializedName("product")
@Expose
private List<Product> product = null;

public String getTitle() {
return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
this.title = title;
}

public List<Product> getProduct() {
return product;
}

public void setProduct(List<Product> product) {
this.product = product;
}

}
```

---

```
public class Value {

@SerializedName("valueName")
@Expose
private String valueName;

public String getValueName() {
return valueName;
}

public void setValueName(String valueName) {
this.valueName = valueName;
}

}
```